# How to read words from text file and store into 2 dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

string Firstname,Surname;

cout << "Full name:" <<endl;
cin >> Firstname >> Surname; 

return 0;
```

I want the commands to work if the user only has first name, normally if the user doesn't input the surname it keeps continuously asking them again and again.....

Comment: stackoverflow.com is not homework site. Show us your effort or code.

Comment: Please add at least your own attempts. 1. You want to read from a file: Google how to do it! 2. You want to store something into a two dimensional array: Google it! 3. Merge the two concepts. If any errors occur ask again.

Comment: Guys this is my code for reading the file @MohammadTayyab

Comment: what is your expected output ? @Puneet

Comment: I want it to be stored in 2 dimensional array and then output its first name and second name in one line @MohammadTayyab

Comment: @Puneet check code and replace "File.txt" with your text file name. and tell me if any other confusion.

Comment: @MohammadTayyab Thanks for so much help but i have one more question. What if i want the system to read the whole sentence as one line and store it in the array ???

Comment: In the same 2D array or 1D array? @BeginnerDeveloper?

Comment: I have added both method you just uncomment what do you want getline read whole sentence. In>> read a word.

Comment: @MohammadTayyab I Can't thank you enough for your help.... Sorry but i have a last question.. Is it possible that the user input is cin >> input 1 >> input 2 but i want the same cin to sometime accept one input only....

Comment: Explain it I do not understand.

Comment: @MohammadTayyab I have explained the scenario on top. Pls have a look. Looking forward for your help..

Comment: It you can put NULL where user do not have any last name or you can put Not Available, because in file how you will recolonize who have last name and who do not ? So simply put it nor available

Comment: What if I have to show only one column ?? and only one row and one column ?? @MohammadTayyab

Comment: Run your loop only for once. @BeginnerDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

I have commented my code and make a code to read names from file and store them into 2D string array as you want.

**Text File**

```
James
Will
Bruce 
Wayne
Harry    
Potter
```

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    int count=0;
    ifstream in("File.txt");
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        getline(in, str);
        count++; //counting names
    }
    in.close();
    count = count / 2; //dividing count by 2
    //SYNTAX FOR 2D ARRAY
    string **nameArray = new string*[count]; //making array of count/2
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        nameArray[i] = new string[2]; //evvery index have 2 column one for first name and second for last name
    //2D array done
    in.open("File.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
                   // getline(in,nameArray[i][j]; // if you want to read sentence.not a single word.
            //in >> nameArray[i][j]; //if you want to read name or a single word.
        }
    }
    in.close();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            cout<<nameArray[i][j]<<" "; //Printing [i,j] with first and second name
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        delete[] nameArray[i];
    delete[] nameArray;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
James Will
Bruce Wayne
Harry Potter
```